# SQLAlchemy - Different name for inherited column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have the following sql alchemy models:

```py
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    name = Column(String)

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "manager"
    manager_name = Column(String)
```

I want `manager_name` to represent the column `name` in the base class. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems like this solves the issue:

```py
class Employee(Base):
    __tablename__ = "employee"
    name = Column(String)

class Manager(Employee):
    __tablename__ = "manager"
    manager_name = Employee.name
```